# contenteditable with placeholder and measure in the end (:after)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wv692z10/).

I have a `span` with the attribute `contenteditable` where I can insert a value. It has the `placeholder` working with the CSS's `:empty`, `:before` and `content:attr(placeholder)`.

Now the problem is when I try to put the measure m³ in the end of the value with `:after`. It works in terms of what I want, on top of the line and moving with the value's lenght but, it glitches the caret (blinking text insertion position cursor vertical bar) when you insert a value.

When I say "it glitches" I mean it can be invisible, not blink, or duplicate the visual caret.

Moving the caret "fixes" the problem but if you move it to the end, it "brokes" again.

When I only press [12345](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joVWn.png) (the caret is in the end but a visual non blinking one stays between the 1st and 2nd character) and when I press 12345 and once the left arrow it shows that one and the real caret blinking before the last character.

I understand that the problem with the real caret not showing might be because the `:after` is on top of it, but I don't know why the visual bug/duplication. How can I add a margin/padding so the `:after` is 1 pixel to the right?

Test it, by typing values to understand the problem.

Preference fix with HTML and/or CSS, if not possible, then Javascript.

```css
html{
  background-color: #202020;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: consolas;
  user-select: none;
}
span{
  display: inline-block;
}
.input{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fbbc05;
  color: #ea4335;
  cursor: text;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  outline-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.input br{
  display: none;
}
.input:empty:before{
  color: #8a190f;
  content: attr(placeholder);
}
.input:after{
  content:attr(testattr);
}
```

```html
<body spellcheck="false">
  <span>Number:</span>
  <span class="input" contenteditable id="test" placeholder="865081" testattr=" m&#179"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself.

Comment: I'm not seeing any 'glitch' (Firefox 50)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - Okay.

Comment: @allnodcoms - I'm using Google Chrome if that helps.

Comment: @user7393973 - Yup, I get glitches in Chrome. Not in FF or Safari though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is not happening in every browser it would seem to be an issue with the contentEditable attribute in Chrome.

I would be tempted to use a standard text input, styled accordingly, and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: I can use the placeholder attribute instead of the `:before`, but can I do the `:after` on a [`<input>`](https://jsfiddle.net/wv692z10/1/)? I don't suppose `background-image` would do the trick.

Comment: You can't use :before or :after on a text input, but you can use them on a label...

Comment: [Best](https://jsfiddle.net/wv692z10/2/) I got was this. Couldn't make the `<input>`'s width be equal to the value inside (didn't searched enough yet). It's not perfect, I will see what I can do.